# Lock table on DELETE statement within stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a delete statement in a stored procedure that deletes many rows off a single table (but does not delete the complete table).

I would like to benefit from a possible performance benefit of the `LOCK TABLES` statement in order to force a table write lock, but this is not allowed in a stored procedure. The statement works at session level.

What I could do is, making sure that the client calling the stored procedure does the lock of tables; but I rather control it within the stored procedure.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`

```
START TRANSACTION;

--Make your operation

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Maybe I was not clear, I am looking for using table lock instead of row lock. This will reduce the number of locks, and therefore speed up the process and use less resources. I am not concerned with having the transaction (since that is already implicit I think)

Comment: @BenOotjers There is no performance benefit from using `lock tables`. (Table locks and innodb lock are basically two independent feature that happen at different levels of the database.) If at all, they increase the overhead, although not measurable (unless of course the locks need to wait). Did you test your assumption? (E.g. with `lock; call procedure; unlock` compared to `lock; unlock; call procedure`).

Comment: @Solarflare. I did not test my assumption. I took it for granted after reading it as a suggestion to lock problems (too many). I have just discovered that the lock tables did not work in that sense. So thanks for the explanation that it works differently; I thought it was similar to MSSQL lock granularity, but that was wrong.

Comment: @Solarflare. What I read in the MySQL reference manual for `LOCK TABLES` is this btw: 'Locks may be used to emulate transactions or to get more speed when updating tables'. This was probably what triggered me. I think after reading the details it refers to MyISAM rather than InnoDB.

Comment: @SolarFlare. I tested out the difference, and as you already thought, it does not seem to make a difference whether I use the lock/unlock within the stored procedure. Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it?